# "Permission denied collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status" Error when using #include<openssl/evp.h> in VSCode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, openssl, mingw, permission-denied

So I installed OpenSSL directly following the instructions in the install.txt file you get when cloning the git repository. It installed it seemingly witout issues and is located in C:/Program Files/OpenSSL and C:/Program Files(x86)/OpenSSL. Inside each of those there are 4 folders: bin, html, include, lib.

In VSCode I'm using the code runner extension with the following command:
`g++ -I "C:/Users/Batres/vcpkg/installed/x86-windows/include" "C:/Program Files/OpenSSL/include" simple_functions.cpp -o simple_functions`
the "C:/Users/Batres/vcpkg/installed/x86-windows/include" is a different library called XTensor, which works completely fine as I have tested the code without OpenSSL and it outputs the correct results with no problem. This is the code I'm using, although I doubt it's relevant since it seems to be a complier issue.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstddef>
#include "xtensor.hpp"
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>

/*
def hash_string(string):
    # Truncating at 16 bytes for cleanliness
    hasher = hashlib.sha256(string.encode())
    return hasher.hexdigest()[:16]
    */
std::string hash_string(std::string string) {
    // Truncating at 16 bytes for cleanliness
    std::array<unsigned char, SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH> hash;
    std::array<unsigned char, SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH>::iterator it;

    EVP_MD_CTX* ctx = EVP_MD_CTX_new();
    EVP_DigestInit_ex(ctx, EVP_sha256(), NULL);
    EVP_DigestUpdate(ctx, string.c_str(), string.size());
    EVP_DigestFinal_ex(ctx, hash.data(), NULL);

    // Convert the hash to a hexadecimal string
    std::stringstream ss;
    for (it = hash.begin(); it != hash.end(); it++) {
        ss << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << static_cast<int>(*it);
    }
    return ss.str().substr(0, 16);
}

int main(){
    double a = gen_choose(2,5);
    std::string input = "Hello, world!";
    std::string output = hash_string(input);
    std::cout << std::setprecision(16) << output << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Ignore all the other #includes, they are for different functions that work with no issue. As you can probably see I have some python code commented above my C++ code. Thats simply because it's a function I tried transalting using ChatGPT, but that's not relevant to the error.

This is the line for C++ settings in code-runner.executorMap:
`"cpp": "cd $dir && g++ -I \"C:/Users/Batres/vcpkg/installed/x86-windows/include\" \"C:/Program Files/OpenSSL/lib\" $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt -lssl && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt"`

My compiler is mingw and I'm on Windows 11. I also don't have any antivirus aside from Windows Defender and I've added the library to the exceptions list as well as ld.exe.

I have also tried these commands, all yeilding the same error. I have also tried running all the same commands through a terminal with admin priviliges and it gives the same error. I even copied the folder to a different directory inside my /Documents/ folder and it still didn't help.`g++ -I "C:/Users/Batres/vcpkg/installed/x86-windows/include" "C:/Program Files (x86)/OpenSSL/include" simple_functions.cpp -o simple_functions`
and
`g++ -I "C:/Users/Batres/vcpkg/installed/x86-windows/include" -L "C:/Program Files/OpenSSL/lib" simple_functions.cpp -o simple_functions -lssl`
This last one returns a different error. Insted of being acces denied it seems like none of the functions or variables that I call inside my code are recognised, so this is the type of error: `undefined reference to 'EVP_MD_CTX_new'`, or any other functions or variables I call.

The weird thing is that even though it says access denied when compliling, Intellisense can acess the files just fine, I can right click on the functions and "Go to Definition" and it takes me to my C:/Program Files/OpenSSL/include/openssl/ folder.

If anyone knows how to fix the error I would be very thankful.

Comment: The very last command (with `-L`) looks closer to being correct. All the others appear to be completely incorrect.

Comment: You should understand that these are *linking* errors, intellisense has nothing to do with it, and it's completely normal to get linking errors for functions that intellisense can find.

Comment: Basically the issue is with the openssl library, and the `-L` and `-l` options that you are using. But without knowing more about your installation and your build process I can't really say what the actual mistake is.

Comment: no namespaces have nothing to do with it. `-L` just tells the compiler where to find libraries that you are trying to link with. I assume that your openssl library is located at that location.

Comment: So if the issue is mabye with the openssl library should I try to reinstall it? I've already done that a couple of times and followed the instructions in the install.txt file, so I don't really know why that's happening.

Comment: There is no indication that the library has not been installed incorrectly. As I said the issue is likely with the -l and -L options that you are using.

Comment: Yes OpenSSL installs by default in Program FIles/OpenSSL and Program FIles(x86)/OpenSSL

Comment: Question, what is the filename of the library that you are trying to link with? And where is that file located (i.e. which directory).

Comment: Oh ok, where should I go to check documentation on those?

Comment: Another thing to check, are you doing a 32 bit or 64 bit build?

Comment: If i'm not mistaken the file is `libssl.lib` and it's in `C:\Program Files\OpenSSL\lib`

Comment: How do I check which one it is? Do I just try both? I mean wether it's 32 or 64 bit.

Comment: If you are using vcpkg you should have it compile and build openssl as well. Although with that said `x86-windows` is the wrong triplet for MinGW. That one is for 32 bit msvc. I would expect problems since these are not compatible for c++ libraries. You can get away with c based libraries.

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to try the other on i.e. `-L "C:/Program Files (x86)/OpenSSL"`. 32 bit libraries will be ignored in a 64 bit build, and vice versa. But really you should know whether you are building a 32 bit or 64 bit program.

Comment: `std::cout << sizeof(void*) << '\n';` If that prints 4 you are 32 bit, if it prints 8 you are 64 bit.

Comment: I tried the x86 version and no luck. I also did the `sizeof(void*)` and got 8 so it's 64 bit.

Comment: The library that has the `x86-windows` in it's path is working perfectly though

Comment: I also just tried to run the program but removed the function containing all the openssl stuff and it compiles just fine if I don't make any references to anything in the openssl library, even with `#include <openssl/sha.h>` at the top.

Comment: @Batres Where did you get the library from? You realise that a library for one compiler is not going to be valid for a different compiler?

Comment: @Batres `x86` is 32 bit however. 64 bits would usually be `x64`. When you download it should say 32 bit or 64 bit version.

Comment: @Batres Everything you are saying is consistent with you either linking with the wrong version of the library, or failing to link with any version of the library.

Comment: Avoid spaces in paths. Try putting things in a different location than under `C:\Program Files`